# Unable to install Kaspersky anti virus 2011 on XP

Tags: kaspersky

I recently tried installing Kaspersky antivirus 2011 on my XP (service pack 2) . Everytime I try to install through setup file, it initiates and then I get a pop up message saying Windows XP not compatible ( Sorry could no get the complete error message ) there is also options which come up saying "continue anyway" but it wont allow to click as the system gets hung .

I also tried to skip from incompatible software by following [the instructions on Kaspersky's website](http://support.kaspersky.com/faq/?qid=208281594) by creating a short cut to setup file and modifying the target field in it but still I get the same message.

It also asks me to reboot before I install but it is still the same .

Does this mean that I wont be able to install this antivirus software on my machine ? I also wrote to the Kaspersky support but seems they will take ages to reply.

Comment: IMO, it's doing you a favor.

Comment: Why so reluctant about installing SP3?
Its free!

Comment: @tumchaaditya Some games (I know Mech Warrior 4 is one of them) works on SP2 but will refuse to run, even in compatibility mode, on SP3

Answer (score 1):

Also, you might serious consider using MSE. If you're running XP Professional SP2, it would help to upgrade to SP3, otherwise, why even bother using anti-virus? You're system is vulnerable enough being out of date.

Answer (score 0):

[Kapersky's Support Page](http://www.kaspersky.com/support/kis2011?level=3) says:

> - Microsoft Windows XP Home Edition (Service Pack 2 and above)
> - Microsoft Windows XP Professional (Service Pack 2 and above)
> - Microsoft Windows XP Professional x64 Edition (Service Pack 2 and above)
>
>   - Intel Pentium 800 MHz 32-bit (x86)/64-bit (x64) or above (or compatible) 
>       512 MB available RAM

So what's your computer set up like? Try upgrading it.

Or, get [a different antivirus](https://superuser.com/questions/2/free-antivirus-solutions-for-windows).

Comment: I have Microsoft Windows XP Professional (Service Pack 2 ) X86 , 2GB Ram

Comment: @Guruprasad Upgrading to SP3 may help.

Answer (score 0):

Did you remove any previous installations of AV software first?

This could be a sign of an infected PC also.

Make a boot AV disc then Boot from the disc and scan the hard drive, remove any infections it finds, I prefer the Kaspersky disc.

http://www.techmixer.com/free-bootable-antivirus-rescue-cds-download-list/

Then:
Install free MBAM, run the program and go to the Update tab and update it, then go to the Scanner Tab and do a quick scan, select and remove anything it finds.

http://download.cnet.com/Malwarebytes-Anti-Malware/3000-8022_4-10804572.html

When MBAM is done install SAS free version, run a quick scan, remove what it automatically selects.
http://www.superantispyware.com/download.html

Answer (score -2):

Kaspersky provides a [removal tool](http://support.kaspersky.com/faq/?qid=208279463) to uninstall it.